# Do "Gauntlets of Ogre Power" keep my STR at 19 when I'm attacked by Shadows?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, monsters

A hit by a Shadow reduces my Strength by 1d4. Wearing the Gauntlets of Ogre Power, will I only notice the change when my (natural) STR score drops to zero? I.e. being hit by a shadow, losing STR in the process, on my next attack will I still attack with 19 STR?

Comment: Related, though not official, [tweets from JC on just this question](https://www.sageadvice.eu/if-a-character-wearing-gauntlets-of-ogre-power-has-its-str-drained-by-a-shadow/).

Answer (score 32):

Looking at the description of Gauntlets of Ogre Power in the DMG, page 171 (emphasis is mine):

> **Your Strength score is 19 while you wear these gauntlets.** They have no effect on you if your Strength is already 19 or higher.

This mentions nothing about what happens if your "natural" Strength gets reduced to 0, so I read that to mean that all the time you are wearing these, you get to proceed using a Strength of 19.

Comment: While I like your answer (it is a magical item after all) there are some different ways to parse this.  I was going to provide a link to an interesting discussion on this at GiTP but my search Fu failed me.  Sorry.