# Aid spell cast multiple times

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, stacking

When you cast an **Aid** spell for a *second time* on the same character, do they gain the healing benefits (since you can heal people multiple times)?

I saw this post: [Can casting the Aid spell stack on the same targets?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/111832/can-casting-the-aid-spell-stack-on-the-same-targets), but it doesn't address the healing portion of the spell.

I understand that spell effects usually do not stack. PHB 206:

> The effects of the same spell cast multiple times don't combine,
> however. Instead, the most potent effect — such as the highest bonus —
> from those castings applies while their durations overlap, or the most
> recent effect applies if the castings are equally potent and their
> durations overlap.

But, Aid heals 5 hp each time ... so, wouldn't those stack? (couldn't you benefit from 5 hp each time you cast Aid?).

And, I would assume that the Max HP benefit from the spell **doesn't** stack. As per the PHB quote above.

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate since it has been asked before. However, I found the current answer to the linked duplicate to be a bit lacking, so I’ve posted a bounty asking for answers to provide details that would more directly address the problem as described in your question here.

Comment: I'm more curious about the HP (healing) benefit stacking. Basically because you can "heal" as many times as you want. The other page doesn't specific that.... (hence why I posted this).  I edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: The other question does cover that, the answer just fails to address the question in sufficient detail, hence the 500 point bounty I’ve put on it, explaining the issue.